# Sorting a dictionary and then replace the values by ranking

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a dictionary (representing the values for all the nodes of a graph) and I would like to replace it by the ranking of each point in this dictionary.

It looks like this:

I am taking the value from:

```
A = nx.degree_centrality(G)
```

giving:

```
A := {0: 0.0012082158679017317, 1: 0.002013693113169553, 2: 0.002013693113169553, 3: 0.0012082158679017317,...
```

I did this:

```
Abis = {k: v for k, v in sorted(A.items(), key=lambda item: item[1], reverse=True)}
```

getting

```
Abis := {1244: 0.06766008860249698, 270: 0.031413612565445025, 1562: 0.029802658074909383,...
```

Now, I have no idea how to create Atiers such that, I get:

```
Atiers := {1244: 1, 270: 2, 1562: 3,...
```

I would like to create a new dictionary from Abis such that I can get the ranking following this criteria.

If you have any idea how you can do this directly from A, I would also be happy with that. I am thinking about it for an hour with success.

Comment: By `rank` do you mean its place in the sorted order?

Comment: yes that's what I mean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try enumerate:

```
Atiers = {k: i for i, (k,v) in enumerate(sorted(A.items(), key=lambda item: item[1], reverse=True), start = 1)}
```

Comment: `enumerate` has a `start` parameter - you could start enumerating at 1.

Comment: @wwii Thanks for info.

Comment: You can capture the key and value separately with a tuple: `{k:i for i,(k,v) in enumerate(sorted(A.items(),key=lambda item: item[1], reverse=True),1)}`

Answer (score 0):

```
Atiers = {}
for (i, k) in enumerate(Abis.keys()):
   Atiers[k] = i
```